# Find two non-singular matrices such that $AB=-BA$

Tags: matrices

Question is precisely the title. I've been trying to come up with an example for an hour now and haven't found one. Do such matrices, $A$ and $B$ exist?

Comment: Oh they do, they do....

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown They do not.

Comment: It is not true if the dimension is odd.

Comment: Oh, they do, they do, they do.... @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown RIght. I realized just before Tsemio pointed it out that this depends on whether $\det(-A)=\det(A)$, ie on the parity of the dimension.

Comment: So let $A,B$ be even square matrices. Then we have that $\det{AB}=\det{BA}=\det{A}\det{B}$? So certainly such matrices exist. But I am still unable to come up with a simple example.

Comment: Try $A=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}$ @W.Ryan

Comment: So $A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=I$ would work as examples?

Comment: @W.Ryan not the identity matrix.  $I$ commutes.

Comment: Take a look at the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices).

Answer (score 1):

$A=$

\begin{bmatrix} 1& 1\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}

and $B=$

\begin{bmatrix}
0& -2\\ 2&0\end{bmatrix}

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you might construct an example of this yourself, via brute force. I'm going to change the notation a bit to make it easier (for me at least). Let
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} \\ X = \begin{bmatrix} x & y \\ z & w \end{bmatrix} $$
We require $AX+XA=O$, where $O$ is the $2\times 2$ matrix of all zeroes. To go further, I will require that $A,X,AX,XA \neq O$ (otherwise it is trivial). Computing the products gives us
$$ AX = \begin{bmatrix} ax+bz & ay+bw \\ cx+dz & cy+dw \end{bmatrix} \\ XA = \begin{bmatrix} ax+cy & bx+dy \\ az+cw & bz+dw \end{bmatrix} $$
And so, the requirement that their sum is the zero matrix breaks down to 4 equations:
$$ 2ax+bz+cy = 0 \\ 2dw + bz + cy = 0 \\ b(x+w) + y(a+d) = 0 \\ c(x+w) + z(a+d) = 0 $$
Subtract the first two equations and add the last two equations to get two new equations
$$ ax=dw \\ (b+c)(x+w)+(y+z)(a+d) = 0 $$
One potential choice here is to just make $a=d=x=w=0$. That satisfies both conditions, and simplifies the remaining equations for us down to one:
$$bz+cy = 0$$
If $bz$ and $cy$ are both 0, then $AX = XA = O$ which I wanted to avoid. So let's pick the next simplest one: $bz = -1, cy=1$. We can accomplish this by letting $b=c=y=1, z=-1$.

Thus, with this choice, we have
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\ X = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \\ AX = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \\ XA = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix} 
$$
and so $AX+XA = O$ as required.